Angular DI can't resolve token for same class from different WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE
I'm using ngx-mat-select-search and it's complaining about missing MatLegacySelect provider that is clearly provided. I started using a dynamic import when this started occuring if that helps. But even though I'm using peerDependencies and marking them as external. It looks like Webpack has created 2 copies of MatLegacySelect in different "modules", so Angular thinks the classes are different tokens for DI. Any ideas on what causes this?


You likely have dependencies that are pulling different versions of @angular/material.

@MatthieuRiegler everything is using @angular/material@^15.0.0

there is only one entry in yarn.lock

@Novaterata please share the minimal reproducible example or a stackblitz where the issue happens for debugging

please share your module structure and show which module is providing, and which module is trying to access.

This is a huge repo, I'm not going to be able to do that

I worked around this by copying the relevant code from the library which I guess re-arranged the webpack modules so that it was the same class. One thing I noticed was that the NgxMatSearchSelectModule doesn't actually import MatLegacySelectModule itself. I don't know, really annoying bug, moving on...
